# Qt full-screen for Lazarus app

Tags: qt, lazarus

I use Lazarus (1.7), Linux with Qt widgetset.
How to go to full-screen mode, and go back after?

Questions about full-screen for C++ don't help here, I need it in Lazarus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not done it but I would give a try to the form's windowstate property.

You can see the possible settings in the object inspector:
wsNormal
wsMaximized
wsMinimized
wsFullScreen

May be as simple as setting the windowstate progromatically.

Comment: I also found that `ShowWindow(Handle, sw_showfullscreen)` does it.